# Python: How to speed up lemmatisation if I check the POS for each word?

Tags: python, nlp, lemmatization

I am new to NLP. I wish to lemmatise. But understand that for WordNetLemmatizer, it depends on the type of words passed in Noun, Verb, etc.

Hence I tried the below code but it is very slow. Basically all my text are saved in a column called "Text" in df. I use the pre_process(text) function by looping each row (Option 1) but it is v slow.

I tried apply (Option 2) , but it just as slow.
Any way to speed up? Thank you!

```
from nltk import WordNetLemmatizer, pos_tag
import pandas as pd

def pre_process(text):
 
    words_only = words_only.lower().split()    

    lem = WordNetLemmatizer()
    words_only1=[]
    for j in range(0, len(words_only)):
        
        pos_label = (pos_tag(words_only)[j][1][0]).lower()
        word=words_only[j]
        
        if pos_label == 'j': pos_label = 'a'    # 'j' <--> 'a' reassignment
        
        if pos_label in ['r']:  # For adverbs it's a bit different
            try:
                word=wordnet.synset(word+'.r.1').lemmas()[0].pertainyms()[0].name() # Could have errors for words like 'not'
            except:
                word=lem.lemmatize(word)

        elif pos_label in ['a', 's', 'v']: # For adjectives and verbs
            word=lem.lemmatize(word, pos=pos_label)

        else:   # For nouns and everything else as it is the default kwarg
            word=lem.lemmatize(word)
        
        words_only1.append(word)
    
    words_only=words_only1
    return( " ".join(words_only)) 


df=pd.read_excel( 'C:/Users/Desktop/TEST.xlsx', 
                   sheet_name='Text', 
                   engine='openpyxl')

**Option 1**
num_text = df.shape[0]
clean_text= []
for i in range(0, num_text):
    clean_text.append(pre_process(df['Text'].iloc[i]))


**Option 2**
df_bd['Processed Text']=df['Text'].apply(pre_process_bow)
clean_text= df['Processed Text'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick review of your method, I suggest you to call `pos_tag` outside of the `for` loop. Otherwise, you call this method for every word, which could be slow. This could already speed up the process a bit, depending on the complexity of `pos_tag`.

Note: I suggest you using `tqdm`. This gives you a nice progress bar and lets you estimate how long it takes.

```
from tqdm import tqdm

def pre_process(text):
    words_only = words_only.lower().split()    

    lem = WordNetLemmatizer()
    words_only1=[]
    pos_tags = pos_tag(words_only)
    for word, word_pos_tag in tqdm(zip(words_only, pos_tags), total=len(words_only)):
        pos_label = word_pos_tag[1][0].lower()
        if pos_label == 'j': 
            pos_label = 'a'    # 'j' <--> 'a' reassignment
        
        if pos_label in ['r']:  # For adverbs it's a bit different
            try:
                word=wordnet.synset(word+'.r.1').lemmas()[0].pertainyms()[0].name() # Could have errors for words like 'not'
            except:
                word=lem.lemmatize(word)

        elif pos_label in ['a', 's', 'v']: # For adjectives and verbs
            word=lem.lemmatize(word, pos=pos_label)

        else:   # For nouns and everything else as it is the default kwarg
            word=lem.lemmatize(word)
        
        words_only1.append(word)
    
    return(" ".join(words_only1))
```